# How can you add a menu in a main form from a dll?

Tags: vb.net, reflection, dll, interface, menu

I have a main form that reference to a dll. Inside the dll is also a form that will add additional menu in the main form that calls it. How can I do that? Please show sample codes. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear the interaction between those forms but I think you have to pass a main form reference to the other form allowing it to modify main form controls.

Something like this:

MainForm:

```
Form2 form2=new Form2(this);
```

Form2:

```
private MainForm mainForm;
public Form2(MainForm mainForm)
{
this.mainForm=mainForm;
}

private void DoSomething()
{
this.mainForm.Controls. ....
}
```

**updated**

You can also use reflection or dynamic type.

look here:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/csharpreflection.aspx

or here for use of dynamic:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx

those example are in c# but it is easy to convert in vb.net with a tool like this:

http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: I have a MainForm.exe that reference to Library.dll. In the library i have a method there that based on logic will add a new menu in the MainForm.exe or even manipulate its MenuItems.enable properties. Basically my problem is how can I access the MainForm.exe controls from the methods inside the Library.dll.